# Disable Appstats logging

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appstats

I'm using Appstats as documented here:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html

It works fine, but every request now logs an info message like this:

> Saved; key: **appstats**:039300, part: 65 bytes, full: 12926 bytes, overhead: 0.000 + 0.004; link: http://example.com/stats/details?time=1290733239309

Is there a way to disable the log messages, while leaving Appstats running?

Maybe I could just take my own copy of ext/appstats/recording.py and comment out the call to logging.info()? Or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [sample appstats config file](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/appstats/sample_appengine_config.py).  You could configure appstats to only run for a percentage of your requests;  that should reduce the number of logging messages but you'll still have the information.

If you want to patch appstats, you should take a look at line [303](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py#303) in `/google/appengine/ext/appstats/recording.py`.  If you're using webapp it should be very easy to simply [monkey-patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) appstats by replacing its save method with its _save method.

Also, submit a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request) and post a link to the groups.  I think being able to disable the logging call is a valid request; they do tend to clutter the logs up a bit.

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone else is interested, here's how I removed the logging using Robert's monkey-patch suggestion.

The standard approach to insert appstats is like this:

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):     
    from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording     
    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)     
    return app
```

This is what I did instead:

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):     

    from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording

    def save(self):
        try:        
            self._save()      
        except Exception:
            pass

    recording.Recorder.save = save

    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)

    return app
```

This retains the original save() function's "ignore all exceptions" behaviour, but removes all of the logging around it.

Comment: This seems like a lot of trouble to go to in order to remove one (harmless, informative) log message.

Answer (score 2):

Appstats' author here. Why do you want to disable the logging? I'm not saying that you shouldn't -- just that I'm surprised you want to disable it since I don't understand your reason. If it's a reasonable use case we can probably just add a configuration flag to disable it.

Comment: Hi Guido, when checking stats I am generally checking the performance of a request I have just made, so I just go to the /_ah/stats/ URL and click one of the last few requests. I therefore don't use the stats links in the logs, and so adding an info log for every request just clutters up the logs. Sometimes I want to review all info-level logs, and if every request has logged a stats line, I can't see the other logs in amongst the noise. Thanks.

Comment: I basically would like to have appstats running on my development machine all the time, instead of having to go enable it and perform whatever action I want to track again. So 99% of the time the appstats logging is just random noise that distracts from my personal debugging/logging.

Comment: If you really think these logging entries are too annoying you could just override or monkey-patch Recorder.save() to call _save() -- everything else it does is redundant.  You could file a feature request in our tracker to make this logging optional -- but it's going to get a low priority.